# Body of question too long

Tags: discussion, support

I tried to ask a question on the main site, but I got a message that said that the body was too long:

> Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 38011.

It's because of my code,

Should I first ask for help simplifying the code? Put something in the comments? Create a link? Is there something else I should do to try and fit this in? Surely, I am not the first person to have this problem. I had a feeling it's better just to ask here on meta before trying anything, Just in case.

Comment: The best way is to try to isolate the part of your code that is causing the problem. Surely not all of it is problematic. Second best is to put the code on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) and link to it here.

Comment: And be aware that if your code is overwhelmingly large, the chances of getting an answer shrink drastically. This is the other reason you should try hard to reduce your code to the problematic part.

Comment: @halirutan Thank you, I have shrunken my code, a bit. I wasn't sure when I posted this question that I'd be able to